# In CSS, how can I reset a button's default browser-given styles?

Tags: html, css, web-component, shadow-dom

i suspect there's a problem with the way browsers are applying default styles onto things like `<button>` elements

to fully understand my conundrum, this involves the shadow dom, and i'll explain that at the end, however for now, let's just focus on a version of the problem i have isolated to a simple question about CSS:

**how can i reset a `<button>` to it's original browser default styling?**

i've tried setting properties like `border: initial;`, and `border: unset;` and `border: inherit;`, but in every case, setting any of these css properties on a button element causes the browser to release any of its default styling

please see the [following example on codepen](https://codepen.io/ChaseMoskal/pen/ewZvNy)

```
<button>control</button>

<button id="b1">b1</button>
<button id="b2">b2</button>
<button id="b3">b3</button>

<button id="b4">b4</button>
<button id="b5">b5</button>
<button id="b6">b6</button>

<style>
  #b1 { background: initial; }
  #b2 { background: unset; }
  #b3 { background: inherit; }

  #b4 { border: initial; }
  #b5 { border: unset; }
  #b6 { border: inherit; }
</style>
```

in this example, the first button is a control, so we can see the default browser styling

on the buttons where we try to reset `background`, the button totally changes style, the background disappears, and even the border changes

on the buttons where we try to reset `border`, the button totally changes, but oddly in a different way -- here the border disappears, and the background changes

what explains these strange and unexpected results?

why do i need to reset a button, you ask? that seems like a weird thing to do, you think? consider my use case involving web component and the shadow dom:

- i'm using the shadow dom with some web components
- i want to allow users to OPTIONALLY set styles on some shadow `<button>`s
- so i set `button { border: var(--button-border); }`

  - however even when the user doesn't supply `--button-border`, the button is visually manged and browser styles are not applied
- even setting `button { border: var(--button-border, initial); }` and the other examples don't work
- how can i give the users of my components a hook to style the buttons away from the default, however leaving intact the default buttons when they decide not to apply any button styles?

i feel like i'm stuck in a pickle here, and the browser might not have an answer to this problem — i fear that i'll have to either abandon the default styling for buttons within my components (bad practice, the default buttons are meant to be familiar to users), otherwise abandon any custom styling to the buttons (bad for designers that's for sure) — is there any hope to salvage this situation?

Comment: problem reproduces in both chrome and firefox

Comment: Default values for both, `background` and `border`, are `none`.

Comment: @panther — that makes sense, but unfortunately setting those proeprties to `none` doesn't give the desired effect —  i've added a test which demonstrates this to the codepen example: https://codepen.io/ChaseMoskal/pen/ewZvNy

Comment: And desired effect is? Show me how the buttons you want.

Comment: @panther — the desired effect is to make the buttons look the same as the "control" button in the example — i want to reset a button's css properties such that the default browser user agent styles are displayed — the same as a button that has no styling applied whatsoever — i need to specify "empty" values which are equivalent to no value being supplied at all — see my explanation about my shadow dom use-case for more insight into why this is necessary

Comment: `appearance: button` (and vendor prefixes) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
button {
     background: none;
     border: none;
     padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: it's a good try thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work — i added the test for this to my codepen example: https://codepen.io/ChaseMoskal/pen/ewZvNy

Comment: please take some time to explain how this solves the problem so that other with similar problem can know the issue clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `all: unset` without forgetting to add outline on focus which is important for accessibility.

```
button {
  all: unset;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
  outline: blue 1px auto;
}
```